# How to reset Yahoo mail password when you forget secret questions but have email forwarding to another mail?

Tags: passwords, yahoo

I have an old Yahoo e-mail address for which I forgot both the password and answers to secret questions. When I still knew the password, I have setup POP download on my current Gmail account so I can still receive emails sent to the Yahoo address.

When I try to use the "I have a problem with my password" feature, the only way to continue is by answering the secret questions, but I don't remember the answers.

Is there a way to reset the Yahoo password when I can still read emails but don't remember the answers to the secret questions?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to actually contact Yahoo! personally, explain the issue of you forgetting the password and ask them to verify you using the Gmail account that you have forwarded emails to.